# Edit Configuration custom specific instrumentation runner missing property

Tags: android, android-studio

```
Android Studio 2.3 RC 1
Build #AI-162.3742087, built on February 16, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-b06 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

I have created my own custom test runner that I want to use to run my instrumentation espresso tests.

I have entered this in the `build.gradle` file:

```
testInstrumentationRunner "me.androidbox.busbymovies.CustomTestRunner"
```

I have created my espresso tests, but under `Edit Configuration` there is no property to change from the default `InstrumentationRunner` to my custom one.

[image]

In earlier configuration there used to be a property called:

```
Specific Instrumentation Runner (Optional)
```

When I run my tests I get the error:
Cannot find any tests

```
Test running failed: Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{me.androidbox.busbymovies.debug.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner}
```

Before when I used to do this it was easy to switch to another instrumentation runner.

Many thanks for any suggestions on how to change your default test runner to your custom one,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the answer to my question.

My mistake was that I need to remove my `Instrumented Test` from the `Edit Configuration` and add a new one.

My `build.gradle` file was ok, and that is all you need to do to get this to work under the Android Studio 2.2.

Comment: Argh, so much time wasted figuring out a silly thing like this! Thanks tho. Deleted it and added a new one and didn't need to edit that missing property at all.

Comment: Same problem, didn't find the Instrumentation Runner field on the configuration, do you know if there is one? So weird to have to delete and add again

Comment: i have the same problem. and the solution is not working for me. android studio version 3.0.1

Comment: @Orientos are you trying to use a custom test runner? if you're new to android espresso and following tutorials, you can ignore parts that say edit the 'Specific instrumentation runner' in Run menu | Edit Configurations as this is removed in new Android Studio and just specified in build.gradle. apologies if you are using a custom test runner

Comment: @georgiecasey I am trying to run using a custom test runner but cant find a way to make Android studio to detect it automatically, already set the class on my gradle script with `testInstrumentationRunner "com.package.SomeCustomRunner"`, but everytime I  run my instrumented tests Android studio says `No tests were found`